# Writing Entities using DefaultHttpResponseWriter

Tags: java, apache-httpcomponents

Using apache httpcomponents core I have a `BasicHttpResponse` with an associated `StringEntity` that I'd like to send out through a `HttpResponseWriter` of some kind.

I though I could use a `DefaultHttpResponseWriter` but looking at its implementation it seems to only  write the header data. This makes sense as I'm only receiving the header. I'd like to write out the whole message, entity data included.

Is there a class that will do this as part of the basic core distribution? It doesn't seem like this should be an uncommon use case but I can't find anything.

I'm tempted to just add a writeTo of my own, but that seems hacky. Are there better ways than this?

```
    logger.info("Sending response");
    HttpTransportMetricsImpl metrics = new HttpTransportMetricsImpl();
    SessionOutputBufferImpl sob = new SessionOutputBufferImpl(metrics, 1024);
    sob.bind(_os);//writes to this buffer go to the output stream/socket
    DefaultHttpResponseWriter responseWriter = 
                 new DefaultHttpResponseWriter(sob);
    responseWriter.write(resp);
    sob.flush();
    if (null != resp.getEntity()) {
        resp.getEntity().writeTo(_os);
    }
    sob.flush();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only missing bit is selecting an appropriate content codec / delineation strategy

```
HttpTransportMetricsImpl metrics = new HttpTransportMetricsImpl();
SessionOutputBufferImpl sob = new SessionOutputBufferImpl(metrics, 1024);
sob.bind(_os);//writes to this buffer go to the output stream/socket
DefaultHttpResponseWriter responseWriter = new DefaultHttpResponseWriter(sob);
responseWriter.write(resp);
StrictContentLengthStrategy contentLengthStrategy = new StrictContentLengthStrategy();
long len = contentLengthStrategy.determineLength(resp);
OutputStream outputStream;
if (len == ContentLengthStrategy.CHUNKED) {
    outputStream = new ChunkedOutputStream(2048, sob);
} else if (len == ContentLengthStrategy.IDENTITY) {
    outputStream = new IdentityOutputStream(sob);
} else {
    outputStream = new ContentLengthOutputStream(sob, len);
}
if (null != resp.getEntity()) {
    resp.getEntity().writeTo(outputStream);
}
// Must be closed, especially when using chunk coding 
// in order to generate a closing chunk
outputStream.close();
sob.flush();
```

Comment: I guess I was surprised that saying write(resp) still made me do the entity myself rather than taking care of everything. I suppose it's good to know I haven't missed anything obvious. Thanks!

Comment: @Paul Rubel: The processes of writing out the message head and the message body are decoupled because one may need to send one or several informational messages (1xx) in-between.